# Writing a dictionary with one key and several values to a file in python

Tags: python, file, dictionary

```
file_name=raw_input("Where would you like to save the file?(the file name will be dits)")
    output=open(file_name+"dits.txt","w")#saves the path
    k=person.keys()
    output.write(k)
    v=person.values(k)
    i=0
    for xrange in 3:# prints the values into a readable file
        output.write(v)
        output.write(" ")
        i=i+1
    output.close()
```

Im trying to save a dictionary into a file 
the dictionary has 1 key and 3 values

```
person[name]=(bd,email,homepage)
```

this is the way I saved my dictionary 
What is the problem with my code? I've been trying to fix it for about a hour 
thanks!

Comment: `for xrange in 3`: Integers are not iterable. Probably you wanted: `for i in xrange(3):...`

Comment: Why are you incrementing a counter?

Comment: Because I know there are 3 values so that the loop will end when the values end

Comment: A lot of this stuff here is unnecessary. You're not incrementing anything in your for loop (which itself is not necessary).

Try something like this: `outstr = " ".join(v); output.write(outstr);`

Comment: Tried it still not working, Its giving me expected a character buffer object

Comment: Whoa, no, stop.  Use `json`, `shelve`, or `pickle` to handle your data serialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not need a user readable representation, take a look at the [pickle module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) which does object serialization.

If you need something readable, a [JSON encoder](http://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) is included in the standard library, wjich will serialize the basic datatypes (strings, numbers, lists, dictionaries).

Comment: I need to use the core commands of python for file saving like write

Comment: If this is homework, [please mention](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812) it somewhere in your question.

Comment: By that do you mean you want to avoid importing modules? If so, why?

Answer (score 1):

Your general approach is wrong here and I don't know if I should be doing your homework, but here's a version of the program that you wrote that works:

```
# Request the file name
file_name=raw_input("Where would you like to save the file?(the file name will be dits)")

# Open the file
output=open(file_name+"dits.txt","w")
keys=person.keys()

# Iterate through the keys and write the values to each line
try:
    for key in keys:
        output.write(key+" ")
        output.write(" ".join([str(val) for val in person[key]]))   # Write all values to a line
        output.write("\n")
finally:
    output.close()
```

It's a little more general than yours (just writes the string version of all values to the file), but I figure someone with less specific needs might read this at some point.

**Note**: This is only for if you specifically want a space-delimited list of keys plus the values in the way the original question was worded. For anyone without these very specific requirements, I agree that pickle or json or some other standard serialization format is preferable!